# Magnetic levitation without any microcontroller

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, resistors

[image]

The above image is taken from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OI_HFnNTfyU&ab_channel=ImperialCollegeLondon).

It uses an electromagnet with two sets of windings which have DC current travelling opposite each other to generate eddy currents in the aluminium plate which helps it levitate.

Are the two different sets of windings  powered by DC and not AC?

Is this the magical technology used in our modern trains?

Comment: This is more suited for Physics.SE...

Comment: They need AC current, and I'm pretty sure it needs only one coil.  Either the YouTube clip is poor, or they meant AC and it didn't come across that way.

Comment: @TimWescott, one coil only? The professor in the video says 2 coils :). One coil would not balance  it

Comment: @All - To avoid anyone suggesting that the professor in the video might be able to help: The info below the video on YT explains this is a "1975 presentation by Professor Eric Laithwaite (1921-1997)" so the professor died in 1997.

Comment: See this video at 44' ... https://www.palais-decouverte.fr/fr/explorer-nos-contenus/les-classiques-du-palais/experiences-delectromagnetisme

Comment: I felt so sorry for Prof Laithwaite about that lecture at the royal institution on gyroscopes, made the guy hard to take seriously and was a very public mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In order to produce eddy currents in the plate, the magnetic field must vary with time. For the magnetic field to vary, the current in the electromagnets must vary. There may be a DC component in the windings currents, but it is the AC component that is inducing the eddy currents.

It could possibly be *pulses*, with the current in each pulse flowing in the same direction. Such a setup would have both an AC component and a DC component to the current. Or it could be purely AC.

Comment: So, the inner coil would be powered by AC current whereas the outer coil would be powered by an inverted AC current (opposite of first coil)?

Comment: It could be. I don't know the details of that setup.

Comment: Did you watch the video?

Comment: No. I'm on a bus with limited internet at the moment. Perhaps later.

Comment: @jessicasmith I watched the video. I had actually watched many years ago. Yes, the current flows one way around one coil, then the other way around the other coil.

Comment: Hi, so one of the coil is powered by AC sine wave and another by AC inverted sine wave or both of them use dc ?

Comment: Jessica, In such levitation systems, the plate often tends to slide off to one side (like standing an egg on one end). Two coils *might* be used to provide a "well" where the plate not only levitates, but tends to sit stably inside the "well" when disturbed. This answer is properly cautious about content of AC/DC because the description of achieving stability is missing.

Comment: @jessicasmith They're connected together, probably in series. Same power source.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for your insight

Comment: @TimWilliams, so this means that the inner coil would be powered by AC current whereas the outer coil would be powered by an inverted AC current (opposite of first coil) but all from the same voltage source?  So, its 180 degree phase shift right?

Comment: @jessicasmith Correct.

Comment: @jessicasmith, Re, "...powered by an inverted AC current..." You could think of it in that way, but it might be easier to just think of the two coils being wound in opposite directions. Same current flows through both coils (it _must_ be so if they are connected in series,) but one coil is wound clockwise, and the other is wound counter clockwise.

Comment: @TimWilliams, hi, thanks for replying, what should be the recommended AC frequency :) in this case ?

Comment: @SolomonSlow , hi, thanks for replying, what should be the recommended AC frequency :) in this case ?

Comment: 50Hz works well enough, as you can see. Have also done it up at 10kHz or so as induction levitation melting.

Answer (score 1):

The current must be AC and there must be a phase difference between the two coils, which requires the addition of capacitance or (perhaps more likely in this case) three phase power.

There are not that many maglev trains in operation. The Shanghai demonstration train uses German technology and (I believe) closed loop control with electromagnets rather than passive control. It gets up to 400+ km/h on the short trip from Pudong airport to a connecting metro station. Doesn't feel all that fast since it's very smooth. I believe there is (or was) a similar short line in Europe.

The new Chinese 600km/h maglev prototype reportedly uses rare earth permanent magnets for the levitation. Obviously there would also need to be some added complexity to make it a stable configuration, perhaps closed-loop control of electromagnets.

I'm not sure that the amount of copper and iron using the principles demonstrated in Prof. Laithwaite's video are economically practical, and it would constantly consume quite a bit of energy just levitating the heavy train unless superconducting magnets were used (probably requiring cryogens and introducing a whole new set of problems).

Comment: Hi sir, phase difference is 180 degrees apart right because the 2 sine waves must be inverted to each other ?  :)

Comment: @jessicasmith No, I believe the phase difference will be less than 180 degrees. It certainly is in the linear motor demonstration. Otherwise it would not be directional.

Comment: Dear sir, So what's should be the phase difference between these 2 coils ?  I will try to test out the demonstration :)

Comment: Try 120° for starters.

Comment: Have you tried this demonstration before sir? It is pretty amazing he can achieve levitation without any mircrocontroller :).

Comment: No I have not. I am aware there are some schemes for passive levitation using AC however. One uses resonance. Also it's quite possible to have closed-loop control without a microcontroller, so I assume you mean "without active control" rather than "without any microcontroller".

Comment: For static levitation, phase shift is not needed; the two coils are needed just to provide a low-energy spot within the larger coil's field, so the metal piece can rest in a stable position. Phase shift is required for propulsion however; I suppose it's not clear exactly which question is being asked, so answering both is indeed prudent.

Comment: @TimWilliams, the question is about static stable levitation and not propulsion :) .

Comment: @jessicasmith You can think of the stable levitation as propulsion toward the center from any point outside.

Comment: " I believe there is (or was) a similar short line in Europe." The world's first commercial maglev shuttle operated from 1984 to 1995 between Birmingham International Airport and the nearby Birmingham International railway station in the UK (not AL). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev#Birmingham,_United_Kingdom,_1984%E2%80%931995) lists some other European maglev systems. The Birmingham system was later replaced by a [cable-hauled conventionally supported system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-Rail_Link). (I've used the Air-Rail link but not the maglev.)

Comment: @GrahamNye Seems like the Shanghai one is the longest currently in operation and carrying commercial passengers, if the Wikipedia entry is up to date, at a mere 30km, including low/medium speed maglev like the Beijing subway S1 line. The 31.5km Emsland Germany was the Euro one I was thinking of but it was shut down more than a decade ago. Seems like wheels work fine for high-speed rail up to 350km/h or so.

Comment: Wheels on rails are good for [574.8 km/h (357.2 mph)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TGV_world_speed_record).

Comment: @GrahamNye Test, though, not actual service, which is more like 350km/h, for whatever reason(s).